# how to insert a button or some element into ext.js desktop/Panel?

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, panel, desktop

i want to put some button into desktop, its not my code, from my friend which is abroad. i tried to put it in every place of this code but its not as a button there.

its lot of code for this Desktop View, please help me to understand where to put it.

```
Ext.define("TEST.view.desktop.Desktop", {
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",

    alias: "widget.TEST",

    uses: [
        "Ext.util.MixedCollection",
        "Ext.menu.Menu",
        "Ext.view.View", // dataview
        "Ext.window.Window",

        "TEST.view.desktop.TaskBar",
        // "Ext.ux.desktop.Wallpaper"

        "TEST.view.desktop.Toolbar"

    ],

    requires: [
        "TEST.view.desktop.DataprovidersDataView"
    ],



    activeWindowCls: "ux-desktop-active-win",
    inactiveWindowCls: "ux-desktop-inactive-win",
    lastActiveWindow: null,

    bodyCls: "ux-desktop",

    border: false,
    html: "&#160;",
    layout: "fit",

    xTickSize: 1,
    yTickSize: 1,


    /**
     * @cfg {Array|Store} shortcuts
     * The items to add to the DataView. This can be a {@link Ext.data.Store Store} or a
     * simple array. Items should minimally provide the fields in the
     * {@link Ext.ux.desktop.ShorcutModel ShortcutModel}.
     */
    shortcuts: null,

    /**
     * @cfg {String} shortcutItemSelector
     * This property is passed to the DataView for the desktop to select shortcut items.
     * If the {@link #shortcutTpl} is modified, this will probably need to be modified as
     * well.
     */
    shortcutItemSelector: "div.ux-desktop-shortcut",


    /**
     * @cfg {Object} toolbarConfig
     * The config object for the toolbar.
     */
    toolbarConfig: null,


    /**
     * @cfg {Object} taskbarConfig
     * The config object for the TaskBar.
     */
    taskbarConfig: null,

    windowMenu: null,

    initComponent: function() {


        var me = this;
        me.windowMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu(me.createWindowMenu());
        me.bbar = me.taskbar = new TEST.view.desktop.TaskBar(me.taskbarConfig);
        me.taskbar.windowMenu = me.windowMenu;

        debugger;

        me.tbar = me.toolbar = new TEST.view.desktop.Toolbar;
        me.windows = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
        me.contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu(me.createDesktopMenu());


        me.items = [
            // { xtype: "wallpaper", id: me.id+"_wallpaper" },
        {
            xtype: "TESTdataprovidersdataview",

        }];

        me.callParent();

        me.shortcutsView = me.items.getAt(0);

        // var wallpaper = me.wallpaper;
        // me.wallpaper = me.items.getAt(0);
        // if (wallpaper) {
        //     me.setWallpaper(wallpaper, me.wallpaperStretch);
        // }
    },

    afterRender: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent();
        me.el.on("contextmenu", me.onDesktopMenu, me);
    },

    //------------------------------------------------------
    // Overrideable configuration creation methods

    createDesktopMenu: function() {
        var me = this, ret = {
            items: me.contextMenuItems || []
        };

        if (ret.items.length) {
            ret.items.push("-");
        }


        ret.items.push(
                { text: "Tile", handler: me.tileWindows, scope: me, minWindows: 1 },
                { text: "Show Toolbar", xtype: 'button', scope: me, minWindows: 1 },
                { text: "Cascade-test", handler: me.cascadeWindows, scope: me, minWindows: 1 });

        return ret;
    },

    createWindowMenu: function() {


        var me = this;
        return {
            defaultAlign: "br-tr",
            items: [
                { text: "Restore", handler: me.onWindowMenuRestore, scope: me },
                { text: "Minimize", handler: me.onWindowMenuMinimize, scope: me },
                { text: "Maximize", handler: me.onWindowMenuMaximize, scope: me },
                "-",
                { text: "Close", handler: me.onWindowMenuClose, scope: me }
            ],
            listeners: {
                beforeshow: me.onWindowMenuBeforeShow,
                hide: me.onWindowMenuHide,
                scope: me
            }
        };
    },

    // Event handler methods

    onDesktopMenu: function(e) {
        var me = this, menu = me.contextMenu;
        e.stopEvent();
        if (!menu.rendered) {
            menu.on("beforeshow", me.onDesktopMenuBeforeShow, me);
        }
        menu.showAt(e.getXY());
        menu.doConstrain();

    },

    onDesktopMenuBeforeShow: function(menu) {
        var me = this, count = me.windows.getCount();

        menu.items.each(function(item) {
            var min = item.minWindows || 0;
            item.setDisabled(count < min);
        });
    },

    onWindowClose: function(win) {
        var me = this;
        me.windows.remove(win);
        me.taskbar.removeTaskButton(win.taskButton);
        me.updateActiveWindow();
    },

    //------------------------------------------------------
    // Window context menu handlers

    onWindowMenuBeforeShow: function(menu) {
        var items = menu.items.items, win = menu.theWin;
        items[0].setDisabled(win.maximized !== true && win.hidden !== true); // Restore
        items[1].setDisabled(win.minimized === true); // Minimize
        items[2].setDisabled(win.maximized === true || win.hidden === true); // Maximize
    },

    onWindowMenuClose: function() {
        var me = this, win = me.windowMenu.theWin;

        win.close();
    },

    onWindowMenuHide: function(menu) {
        Ext.defer(function() {
            menu.theWin = null;
        }, 1);
    },

    onWindowMenuMaximize: function() {
        var me = this, win = me.windowMenu.theWin;

        win.maximize();
        win.toFront();
    },

    onWindowMenuMinimize: function() {
        var me = this, win = me.windowMenu.theWin;

        win.minimize();
    },

    onWindowMenuRestore: function() {
        var me = this, win = me.windowMenu.theWin;

        me.restoreWindow(win);
    },

    //------------------------------------------------------
    // Dynamic (re)configuration methods

    getWallpaper: function() {
        return this.wallpaper.wallpaper;
    },

    setTickSize: function(xTickSize, yTickSize) {
        var me = this,
            xt = me.xTickSize = xTickSize,
            yt = me.yTickSize = (arguments.length > 1) ? yTickSize : xt;

        me.windows.each(function(win) {
            var dd = win.dd, resizer = win.resizer;
            dd.xTickSize = xt;
            dd.yTickSize = yt;
            resizer.widthIncrement = xt;
            resizer.heightIncrement = yt;
        });
    },

    setWallpaper: function(wallpaper, stretch) {
        this.wallpaper.setWallpaper(wallpaper, stretch);
        return this;
    },

    //------------------------------------------------------
    // Window management methods

    cascadeWindows: function() {
        var x = 0, y = 0,
            zmgr = this.getDesktopZIndexManager();

        zmgr.eachBottomUp(function(win) {
            if (win.isWindow && win.isVisible() && !win.maximized) {
                win.setPosition(x, y);
                x += 20;
                y += 20;
            }
        });
    },

    createWindow: function(win) {

        var me = this;

        win = me.add(win);

        me.windows.add(win);

        win.taskButton = me.taskbar.addTaskButton(win);
        win.animateTarget = win.taskButton.el;

        win.on({
            activate: me.updateActiveWindow,
            beforeshow: me.updateActiveWindow,
            deactivate: me.updateActiveWindow,
            minimize: me.minimizeWindow,
            destroy: me.onWindowClose,
            scope: me
        });

        win.on({
            boxready: function() {
                win.dd.xTickSize = me.xTickSize;
                win.dd.yTickSize = me.yTickSize;

                if (win.resizer) {
                    win.resizer.widthIncrement = me.xTickSize;
                    win.resizer.heightIncrement = me.yTickSize;
                }
            },
            single: true
        });

        // replace normal window close w/fadeOut animation:
        win.doClose = function() {
            win.doClose = Ext.emptyFn; // dblclick can call again...
            win.el.disableShadow();
            win.el.fadeOut({
                listeners: {
                    afteranimate: function() {
                        win.destroy();
                    }
                }
            });
        };


        return win;
    },

    getActiveWindow: function() {
        var win = null,
            zmgr = this.getDesktopZIndexManager();

        if (zmgr) {
            // We cannot rely on activate/deactive because that fires against non-Window
            // components in the stack.

            zmgr.eachTopDown(function(comp) {
                if (comp.isWindow && !comp.hidden) {
                    win = comp;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }

        return win;
    },

    getDesktopZIndexManager: function() {
        var windows = this.windows;
        // TODO - there has to be a better way to get this...
        return (windows.getCount() && windows.getAt(0).zIndexManager) || null;
    },

    getWindow: function(id) {
        return this.windows.get(id);
    },

    minimizeWindow: function(win) {
        win.minimized = true;
        win.hide();
    },

    restoreWindow: function(win) {
        if (win.isVisible()) {
            win.restore();
            win.toFront();
        } else {
            win.show();
        }
        return win;
    },

    tileWindows: function() {
        var me = this, availWidth = me.body.getWidth(true);
        var x = me.xTickSize, y = me.yTickSize, nextY = y;

        me.windows.each(function(win) {
            if (win.isVisible() && !win.maximized) {
                var w = win.el.getWidth();

                // Wrap to next row if we are not at the line start and this Window will
                // go off the end
                if (x > me.xTickSize && x + w > availWidth) {
                    x = me.xTickSize;
                    y = nextY;
                }

                win.setPosition(x, y);
                x += w + me.xTickSize;
                nextY = Math.max(nextY, y + win.el.getHeight() + me.yTickSize);
            }
        });
    },

    updateActiveWindow: function() {
        var me = this, activeWindow = me.getActiveWindow(), last = me.lastActiveWindow;
        if (activeWindow === last) {
            return;
        }

        if (last) {
            if (last.el && last.el.dom) {
                last.addCls(me.inactiveWindowCls);
                last.removeCls(me.activeWindowCls);
            }
            last.active = false;
        }

        me.lastActiveWindow = activeWindow;

        if (activeWindow) {
            activeWindow.addCls(me.activeWindowCls);
            activeWindow.removeCls(me.inactiveWindowCls);
            activeWindow.minimized = false;
            activeWindow.active = true;
        }

        me.taskbar.setActiveButton(activeWindow && activeWindow.taskButton);
    }
});
```

if im inserting button here it will be so big as whole desktop. such a big buttons i dont need.

```
me.windows = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
me.contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu(me.createDesktopMenu());

me.items = [
    // { xtype: "wallpaper", id: me.id+"_wallpaper" },
{
    xtype: "TESTdataprovidersdataview",
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Help'

}];
```

after comment of Cristoph tried this:
still not working, i see big button on whole dekstop

```
 me.items = [

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 111,
            height:111,
            text: 'Show Toolbar',
            action: 'showToolbar'
        },

        {
            xtype: "TESTdataprovidersdataview"
        }];
```

Comment: it very sad to see how some of people here putting MINUS without helping or saying something, even critic. they just feel some power and doing such a STUPID things! sad!

Comment: I think the question is totally ok, I wish more developers would give such good code snippets.

Comment: Double xtype definition does not work. Where should the button appear? As part of a window, or in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours dealing with that, i realizied how simple it was.

Its all what i needed to implement:

```
 me.items = [

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Show Toolbar',
            maxWidth: 95,
            maxHeight: 32,
            margin: '5%, 800%',
            itemId: 'niceButton',
            align: "right",
            action: 'showToolbar',
            pack: 'center',


            listeners: {
                          mouseout: function() {
                              if (!this.mouseout) {
                                  this.mousedOver = true;
                                  alert('Would you like to show Toolbar');
                              }
                          }
                      }
        },

        {
            xtype: "TESTdataprovidersdataview"
        }];
```